# Design of Python curiosity, why so?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say we have `x = [2,4,5]`. If I do `y = list(x)`, I get back `[2,4,5]` and similarly true for tuples. This is a bit surprising to me, I could have expected `[[2,4,5]]` in the former case. What would have been the motivation for not giving back a list of a list?

Comment: Why would you expect `list(x)` to return `[x]`? The latter is a shorter, clearer way to do that.

Comment: It just seems right to me for the function `list()` to return a list, not the same thing that it took in.

Comment: It does, in fact, return a list.

Comment: Right, but not a list of a list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `list` builtin type takes an *arbitrary iterable* (regardless of type) and creates a *new* list out of it.  Since a `list` instance is iterable, it can be used to construct a new list by iteration.

If you expect `list([1,2,3])` to give `[[1,2,3]]`, why wouldn't you expect `list((1,2,3))` to return `[(1,2,3)]` or `list(x for x in range(10))` to return `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0xef170>]`?

Answer (score 0):

If `list()` is given another list then it creates a list using the given list's members (A copy)